# I am getting parse error while updating the query through perl

Tags: perl, dbi

I tried to update the table in DB using an update query in perl. Am getting the below error

> `SQL Error: couldnt update Server message number=20000 severity=0 state=0 line=0 server=AWSOSA1 text=ERROR=Parse failure on line 1 of statement 'UPDATE alerts.status SET AlertKey='Port 101 Circuit Up down' where Identifier='Link 101 Circuit Up Down Circuit Status Private Cloud uplinks CP0027829 DOWN 101 PC_SOCKET_PROBE', at or near '''`

I tried to print the query and run it in db and it is working there. Not sure why the parse error is coming while running through perl script :-(

Can anybody help?

Below is the query I tried to run through perl:

```sql
UPDATE alerts.status SET AlertKey='Port 101 Circuit Up down' where Identifier='Link 101 Circuit Up Down Circuit Status Private Cloud uplinks CP0027829 DOWN 101 PC_SOCKET_PROBE'
```

Code:

```perl
my $sql1 = "SELECT AlertKey,AdditionalText,Identifier FROM alerts.status where AdditionalText like 'priority' AND Summary like 'Uplink' AND Type=1";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql1);
my $alertkey;
my $str;
$sth->execute() || die "SQL Error: couldnt execute $DBI::errstr\n";

while(my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array())
{
        print "Inside while\n";
        my $str=$row[1];
        print "\nAdditional Text=".$str;
        $alertkey=$row[0];
        print "\nAlert Key before modification=".$alertkey;
        my $regex = qr/"link_index":"(\d+)"/mp;
        if($str =~ /$regex/g)
        {
                my $linkIndex=$1;
                $alertkey='Link '.$linkIndex.' Circuit Up down';
                print "\nAlertKey after modification=".$alertkey;
        }
        my $sql2 = "UPDATE alerts.status SET AlertKey='$alertkey' WHERE Identifier='$row[2]'";
        my $sth1 = $dbh->prepare($sql2);
        $sth1->execute() || die "SQL Error: couldnt update $DBI::errstr\n";;
        print "Number of rows updated :" + $sth->rows;
        $sth1->finish();
        $dbh->commit or die $DBI::errstr;
 }
```

$dbh->disconnect();

Comment: Please add your Perl code and the schemas too ([mcve]), thank you.

Comment: This is my code:

Comment: please always update your question, don't add information via comments.

Comment: I have added the code

Comment: Why are you using random regex options? None of `/mp` or `/g` should be there.

Comment: Don't interpolate variables into your SQL. Use [placeholders](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#Placeholders-and-Bind-Values).

Comment: Why are you calling `prepare` and `execute` separately? Wouldn't [the `do` method](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#do) be more convenient?

Comment: Your code is logically broken. Your loop condition `my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array()` tries to retrieve rows from `$sth`, but your loop body overwrites `$sth` with an `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? How do you know your query is what you claim it is? If you hardcode it in your program, does it throw the same error?

Comment: I tried to use sth1 inside loop but still I face the same error. When I tried to hardcode the query, it updated the db though i got the following error:commit ineffective with AutoCommit enabled

Comment: I am using Sybase

Comment: updated code used.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, your code has several problems. I'm not sure if the following will solve your problem, but at least it doesn't have any of the mentioned issues.

BTW: I took an educated guess based on your regex that the `AdditionalText` column actually contains a JSON string. Then you should use a JSON parser instead of applying a regex.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON qw(decode_json);

# DB setup etc.
use DBI....
my $dbh = ...
...

# Query for alert status
my $query_sth = $dbh->prepare(
    q(SELECT AlertKey,AdditionalText,Identifier FROM alerts.status where AdditionalText like 'priority' AND Summary like 'Uplink' AND Type=1)
);

# Update AlertKey
my $update_sth = $dbh->prepare(
    q(UPDATE alerts.status SET AlertKey=? WHERE Identifier=?)
);

# Execute query
$query_sth->execute()
    or die "SQL Error: couldn't execute $DBI::errstr\n";

# Loop over results
foreach my $row ($query_sth->fetchrow_arrayref) {
    my($key, $text, $id) = @{ $row };
    my $data;

    # Educated guess: $text is actually a JSON string
    eval {
        $data = decode_json($text);
    };
    if ($@) {
        # handle JSON parse errors here...
        next;
    }

    my $link = $data->{link_index};
    unless ($link) {
        # handle missing link index here...
        next;
    }

    # update alert key
    my $alert = "Port ${link} Circuit Up down";
    $update_sth->execute($alert, $id)
        or die "SQL Error: couldn't update $DBI::errstr\n";
}
```

### Alternative without using JSON

**NOTE:** this is *not* recommended. If you have JSON, XML, CSV, whatever...: always use a parser and work in the "parsed" domain.

```perl
    my($key, $text, $id) = @{ $row };

    # NOTE: regex might be incorrect if JSON property "link_index"
    #       is actually a number, not a string (see following line)
    my($link) = ($text =~ /"link_index":\s*"(\d+)"/;
    #         = ($text =~ /"link_index":\s*(\d+)/;
    unless ($link) {
        # handle missing link index here...
        next;
    }
```

Comment: Dont have JSON installed :-( Any idea how the update works when hardcoded.

Comment: I would suggest to install JSON module if you have to write Perl code that has to process/generate JSON. Anyway, I updated my answer with an alternative.

Comment: my problem is that the update query is not taking single quote at the end of the query. Thats why I am getting a parse error. id is a string and i need to put it in between single quotes.

Comment: With placeholders you wouldn't have this problem. Please do try the code improvements I have suggested.

Comment: my $sql2 = "UPDATE alerts.status SET AlertKey=? WHERE Identifier=?";
                my $sth1 = $dbh->prepare($sql2);
                $sth1->execute($alertkey,$id)
                   or die "SQL Error: couldnt update $DBI::errstr\n";;

Comment: facing this error SQL Error: couldnt update Server message number=17001 severity=10 state=0 line=0 server=AWSOSA1 text=No SRV_DYNAMIC handler installed.

Comment: I tried to print $alertkey and $id. They are as expected

Comment: That looks like a different error message. So your original problem seems to be solved. You should probably check the Sybase documentation for this new error message.

Comment: This is what the documentation says:The default handler sends the message “No SRV_DYNAMIC handler installed” to the client. Open Server returns DONE ERROR to the client.

Comment: Can we agree that your original question "parser error in SQL update query" is solved? If yes, then please up-vote and accept the answer you like best. For your new error message: I'm no DBI expert but that looks like driver/configuration issue. I would search if some other DBI user had the same issue or raise a new question for it.